# How to invoke UpdateSource for all bindings on the form?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to invoke UpdateSource for all bindings on the form?

Answer (score 13):

Some time ago I wrote a bunch of helpers for this task.

```
public static void UpdateAllBindingSources(this DependencyObject obj)
{
    foreach (var binding in obj.GetAllBindings())
        binding.UpdateSource();
}

public static IEnumerable<BindingExpression> GetAllBindings(this DependencyObject obj)
{
    var stack = new Stack<DependencyObject>();

    stack.Push(obj);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var cur = stack.Pop();
        var lve = cur.GetLocalValueEnumerator();

        while (lve.MoveNext())
            if (BindingOperations.IsDataBound(cur, lve.Current.Property))
                yield return lve.Current.Value as BindingExpression;

        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(cur);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(cur, i);
            if (child is FrameworkElement)
                stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just call

```
this.UpdateAllBindingSources();
```

from your window and you are done.

Comment: Nice. But.. is there any way to get this working in Silverlight?

Comment: Right, I would also be interested to see a version of that that works in Silverlight.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't find an easy way to port this solution to Silverlight. I'm more of a WPF dev, so my knowledge of SL peculiarities is quite limited.