# Where to call Required.GetBindingExpression when validating empty fields for Enterprise Library's Validation Block

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, enterprise-library

In WPF, typical validation implementations do validation when a property value changes. This presents a problem. If you have a "Required" field and you click a button, the user is not alerted to the empty when they click the button. Since the value did not change, validation does not occur.

There are many approaches to this online whereby you perform the validation explicitly in the code-behind, on a base viewmodel etc. However I am interested in the solution proposed by Microsoft. In particular this applies for the Validation Application Block in the Microsoft Enterprise Library which I am currently using. Microsoft recommends a best practise approach here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664451(v=pandp.50).aspx

In particular they state:

> If the value of the validated control that carries the Required validation attribute is empty to begin with, and remains empty during validation, the source is not updated and validation does not occur. In this particular case the ValidateOnTargetUpdate property will not work either because the null default value of the target will not change. Instead, you can invoke UpdateSource on the binding to force validation to occur, as shown here:

```
this.Required.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

> The validation rule operates in the ConvertedProposedValue step, after the value has been converted but before it is set on the source. This means that value conversion errors must be detected through other mechanism. One approach is to enable the ValidatesOnDataErrors property on the validated binding.

Unfortunately I cannot make sense of this. Where do I call the UpdateSource method?  Which object does `this` refer to in Microsoft's snippet? I am assuming I need to do something like intercept the binding somewhere, but I am not sure.

Comment: Your `Window` class will have that function without required, so if you type that in your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` it will give you `GetBindingExpression` function. This is also available in any `Controls`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. As stated in the comments section we have access to GetBindingExpression in the the window or any controls. I believe Microsoft's intention is that `Required`  is a sample name of a control and `this` refers to the codebehind of the Window, or any other control like Window that has a code-behind.

Furthermore, raising a `PropertyChanged` event as suggested elsewhere for other validation constructions (such as when developers have implemented IDataErrorInfo) does not seem to have the same effect in Microsoft Enterprise Library's Validation Block. Validation does not re-occur by simply raising a PropertyChanged event on the control. This is not specific to required fields. Instead Microsoft suggests performing `UpdateSource` on the control, albeit with reference to required fields.

Here [How to invoke UpdateSource for all bindings on the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150983/how-to-invoke-updatesource-for-all-bindings-on-the-form) is an example for how to achieve an `UpdateSource` on all elements.